# boost/unordered_set: compile error with mingw ()

Tags: boost, mingw, unordered-set

I have a piece of code that uses boost's unordered_set

```
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
boost::unordered_set<string> mySet(100);
```

It compiles and works fine with gcc under unix. When I try cross compiling with mingw32 (gmake 3.8.1) I get the following message:

```
In file included 
from /usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/functional/hash/detail/hash_float.hpp:17,
from /usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:15,
from /usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/functional/hash.hpp:6,
from /usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp:17,
from /usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/unordered_set.hpp:16,
from /mnt/VirtualBoxShare/percolator/src/ProteinProbEstimatorHelper.h:33,
from /mnt/VirtualBoxShare/percolator/src/ProteinProbEstimator.cpp:28:

/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:105: error: expected unqualified-id before 'unsigned'
/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:105: error: expected ';' before 'unsigned'
/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:105: error: declaration does not declare anything
/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:114: error: expected unqualified-id before 'unsigned'
/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:114: error: expected ';' before 'unsigned'
/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:114: error: declaration does not declare anything
```

To me it seems like a template related problem; any suggestions?

Thank you,
Mattia

---

[EDIT]

other boost functionalities are available, for example the lexical cast

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

Comment: What version of MinGW and gcc? Maybe you could use C++0x unordered_set instead of this one from boost?

Comment: What version of Boost? Do you have `#include <string>`? And `using std::string;` or `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @Zuljin sorry, mingw32-boost-1.41.0 and mingw32-gcc-c++-4.4.2. The string header is included and I am using std::string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some typedef breaks the boost cstdint header, which looks like

```
103   using ::int8_t;
104   using ::int_least8_t;
105   using ::int_fast8_t;
106   using ::uint8_t;
107   using ::uint_least8_t;
108   using ::uint_fast8_t;
```

on my system. So, some hero probably defined  "#define uint8_t" instead of "typedef ... uint8_t", and this code consequently breaks.

You might try to to modify your boost/config/platform/win32.hpp and, if that helps, report the bug to the mingw developers.

Comment: You are so right about that. I found in my project there is a "hero" that did the same thing: ``#define uint8_t         unsigned char``